# I am having issues logging into Amadeus self service - I created 2 or more account but same issue cannot login

Tags: http-status-code-401, amadeus

Every time I enter credentials it loads and then get no authorisation message followed by thi space does not exist. [screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwEc9.jpg)

I have changed password successful, created new accounts but can't login.

be presented with profile

Answer (score 0):

That might be linked to an ongoing issue with the registration flow. Waiting for the fix, as a workaround, you can try to register again choosing "Other" as Business area, that should work. In case you get an error like "User already exists", then simply try with a different email.